# How to set the UIColor for each letter in a string

Tags: swift, text, format, uicolor

Is there a simple way to set the colour for each letter in a UILabel in swift? (Or any other text for that matter!)

For example

```
let label = UILabel(frame CGRectMake(100,100,100,100))
label.text = "spell"
label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

But I want the S to be red, the p to be blue, the e to be yellow etc.

Thanks in advance if anyone knows how to do this easily...

I got this to work with help from those below. And added the attributed string to a UIButton title.

```
let mainspring = "spell"
let spellAttrString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: mainString)

        spellAttrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.blueColor(), range: NSRange(location: 0,length: 1))
        spellAttrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.greenColor(), range: NSRange(location: 1, length: 1))
        spellAttrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellowColor(), range: NSRange(location: 2, length: 1))
        spellAttrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSRange(location: 3, length: 1))
        spellAttrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.magentaColor(), range: NSRange(location: 4, length: 1))

        [spellButton .setAttributedTitle(spellAttrString, forState: .Normal)]
```

Answer (score 3):

For creating of the colorful string you should use `NSMutableAttributedString`.

Small example:

```
var attrString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Some text")
attrString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.redColor(), range: NSMakeRange(0, 3))
```

Comment: thanks Oleg. I had to change the range part but now it works.